# Stack Numpy Arrays Without Extra Checks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two Numpy arrays `labels` and `more_labels`. In one case both arrays are 1D, having shapes (m,) and (n,) in another case both arrays are 2D, having shapes (m,k) and (n,k). I would like to combine them so that the resulting array has shape (m+n,) in the 1D case or (m+n,k) in the 2D case.

Currently I'm having to handle the two cases separately, like this:

```
if(labels.ndim > 1):
    numpy.vstack(labels,more_labels)
else
    numpy.hstack(labels,more_labels)
```

Is there a Numpy method to handle both cases together?

Comment: Note that `vstack` and `hstack` use `concatenate`; they have different ways of specifying the axis, and may adjust the number of dimensions.  They are coded in Python, and can be read with ` np.source(np.hstack)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`np.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to join your arrays along a given axis. In this case since you want to join them along the first axis you can just use the default `axis` argument which is set to 0.

> `numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)`
>
> Join a sequence of arrays
>   along an existing axis.

Here is an example:

```
n [18]: a = np.array([1,2, 3])

In [19]: b = np.array([0,0, 3])

In [20]: np.hstack((a, b))
Out[20]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3])

In [21]: np.concatenate((a, b))
Out[21]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3])

In [22]: a = np.array([[1],[2], [3]])

In [23]: b = np.array([[0],[0], [3]])

In [24]: np.vstack((a, b))
Out[24]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [0],
       [0],
       [3]])

In [25]: np.concatenate((a, b))
Out[25]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [0],
       [0],
       [3]])
```